# How to Close Sqlite Connection without explicitly calling Close Method using .NET

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, database-connection, system.data.sqlite

I am creating desktop application in winform that will use Sqlite Database.

So I created Sqlite Helper class that uses `System.Data.SQLite` and each method of that Helper class opens and closes connection.

But now I also added ability to attach additional databases but after Connection is Closed, all attached databases gets lost.

To correct this I modified the class so that the connection is opened in constructor and remains open.

After the application ends, I want that connection to close without explicitly calling the Close method.

Any suggestions how to do that?

Comment: Can you use `using` statement

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal - That would be with a lowercase `u`.

Comment: Not sure how since the helper class is created in the Form_load event and the application uses that class during the lifetime of the application.

Comment: @Oded: Did it Thanks and i aksed you to please vote to close my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10396807/app-that-allows-users-w-no-sql-experience-to-build-sql-queries

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal - I already have. And you know - you can flag the question yourself for moderator attention asking them to delete it.

Comment: Thanks again. Just checked that delete vote increased and I notified moderator for that also.

Comment: Can you override the OnClose method ?

Comment: I am trying to close the connection without relying on users to call that method explicitly after application closes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keeping the connection open for the lifetime of your application is not a good way to go.
I suggest to not follow this route.
On the contrary, I will try to encapsulate the functionality to attach a database inside a method that could be called on the need to use basis.

For example:

```
private static void AttachDB(string fileDB, string aliasName, SQLiteConnection cn) 
{ 
    string sqlText = string.Format("ATTACH '{0}' AS {1}", fileDB, aliasName) 
    SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sqlText, cn) 
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
}
```

then in your code

```
using(SQLiteConnection cn = new SQLiteConnection(GetConnectionString()))
{
     AttachDB(@"C:\SQLite\UserData.sqlite3", "UserData", cn);
     // Do your code here
}
```

Comment: Do you mean to have connections open as short as possible and after opening connection I attach databases?

Comment: Yes, keep the connection open for the shortest time. That's a general rule. NET use [connection pooling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool) to avoid the cost of reinitializing the connection everytime. However SQlite doesn't enable it by default. Use a connectionstring like this `Data Source=filename;Version=3;Pooling=True;Max Pool Size=100;`. [See here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlite)

Comment: I thought of that too but it just seemed more costly to reattach databases each time I use sqlite methods.

Comment: As I have said, I will stay on the known path. However you need to benchmark the time required to attach a database. Also, have you tried if the database is equally lost when connection pooling is active?

Comment: Just tried it with connection pooling is active and it works. Attached databases did not get lost. Thank you.

Comment: How is that code supposed to work? I did it the same way, but the connection was *not* open automatically after instantiating it; I first had to invoke `Open()`. But then, after doing that, it feels somehow wrong, asymmetrical, to not explicitly call `Close()` as well.

Answer (score 5):

`Close` should not disconnect your database but this will only work when .NET connection pooling mechanism is on. Make sure you have that enabled in your connection string:

```
Data Source=filename;Version=3;Pooling=True;Max Pool Size=100;
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how your class is defined, you can use Dispose or a destructor. Or, explicitly call Close() at the end of the program (from within Main, after Run...).

Comment: Dispose and Destructor sounds like what I need. Which one do should I use?

Comment: Like I said, depends on what's in your class already. Read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b(v=vs.80).aspx), [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.finalize(v=vs.80).aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw(v=vs.80).aspx) to help you decide.

Answer (score 1):

In C# there is a special syntax for such situation:

```
using(var connection = new Connection())
{
   //work with connection
}
```

it compiles to something like:

```
Connection connection = null;
try
{
   connection = new Connection();
   //your operations
}
finally
{
   connection.Dispose();
}
```

on calling Dispose() you close connection.

Comment: Not quite - after instantiating the connection, it is *not* open yet - you still have to invoke `Open()`. When doing so, though, it feels somehow wrong, asymmetrical, not to call `Close()` before `Dispose()` ...